# Selenium WebDriver: Actions and TouchActions. When should one or another class be used if the required method is present in both?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

What is the difference between the `Actions` class and `TouchActions`? both have the same description [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/index.html) in official documentation and contain some similar methods. Why two classes instead of one?

When should one or another class be used if the required method is present in both?

Answer (score 0):

One is simulating mouse and keyboard interactions on a screen (e.g. using a desktop).  The other is simulation touch actions with your finger on a screen (think iPad or mobile phone).

Answer (score 0):

Actions class (provided by Selenium) is used to handle mouse keyboard operations for browsers.

TouchActions class (provided by Selenium) is used to handle the operations for browsers in touch enabled devices.

TouchAction (provided by Appium and base class for AndroidTouchAction and IOSTouchAction classes) is used to handle the operations for apps in touch enabled devices.